# Active Record Object Fields Saving as Null in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, save

I created Class "ClassA" that extends ActiveRecord. I added the field "text" with db:migrate. In my controller, I call:

```
class_a_instance = ClassA.new(:text => "bite me")
puts class_a_instance.text
class_a_instance.inspect
class_a_instance.save
```

The first two lines are fine. New class a is created with text "bite me". The puts command works. However, upon calling inspect, the text field is printed as null. The save operation also commits to the database with the text field as null. class_a_instance is defined as a local variable inside of another class (ClassUser).

Schema.rb for class_a

```
   ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20111013231426) do
   create_table "class_as", :force => true do |t|
     t.string   "text"
     t.datetime "created_at"
     t.datetime "updated_at"
     t.integer  "num_users"
     t.integer  "num_events"
     t.integer  "num_events_completed"
   end
```

Using MySQL2 driver. Ruby 1.9. Rails 3.1. I've only been learning rails for 3 weeks so the bug could be very simple. (previously a java programmer)

Thanks!

Comment: ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20111013231426) do

  create_table "class_a", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "text"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "num_users"
    t.integer  "num_events"
    t.integer  "num_events_completed"
  end

Comment: wow that's ugly. i'll put it in the original question too.

Answer (score 0):

> class_a_instance is defined as a local variable inside of another class (ClassUser)

wait are you trying to say that ClassUser has_one or has_many ClassA's ?

I think you need a relation.  First, add a class_user_id integer in the schema for class_as, and then put the relationships in the classes:

in ClassUser: `has_one` or `has_many`

in ClassA: `belongs_to` ClassUser

There are many resources out there to help, google for "rails relations tutorial"

Comment: Ah, I had has_one and belongs_to defined. I actually redefined the objects with scaffold and class_a_instance started saving correctly. I'm not sure what the issue was but will keep playing around with new classes and comparing with scaffold to see what I was missing. thx